# Laravel Eloquent: after() not adding column after a certain column

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Following code generates column in the end rather after the certain column. I am on Laravel 5.1

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('project', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('is_it',['yes','no'])->after('goals')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: This only works in MySQL, are you using MySQL?

Comment: Should have mentioned; no `postgresql`

Answer (score 19):

This is not possible when you are working with PostgreSQL. This function is only supported by MySQL.

In [Column Modifiers Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#column-modifiers), the method *after* is then only highlighted for MySQL and you can also see a discussion about it here: [#14298](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14298).

I hope this clarifies your doubt, regards!

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned it won't work on Postgresql, But this problem also exists within Laravel 8 using MySQL.

It's about how you chain them, this wouldn't work on Laravel 8:

`$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Center::class)->references('id')->on('centers')->after('id');`

But this will:

`$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Center::class)->after('id')->references('id')->on('centers');`.